# Mirantis Fuel 9.2 "Failed tasks: Task[openstack-cinder/7], Task[openstack-cinder/6], Task[openstack-cinder/8]"

Tags: openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder

I have a problem deploying OpenStack environment on an HP server using Mirantis Fuel 9.2. Tried to redeploy the environment a couple of times with different configurations and I still get this error. What's interesting is that it deploys flawlessly on my PC.

I followed this quickstart guide to install Fuel: https://docs.mirantis.com/openstack/fuel/fuel-9.0/quickstart-guide.html

It throws the following error:

```
Deployment has failed. All nodes are finished. Failed tasks: Task[openstack-cinder/7], Task[openstack-cinder/6], Task[openstack-cinder/8] Stopping the deployment process!
```

From the logs of the controller node from Fuel Dashboard (snippet below), it seems that DB is initialized incorrectly. Is there a workaround or a way to fix this?

```
2017-03-06 03:31:31 CRIT    cinder [req-ad264daf-f7be-4389-9a6a-7547d1b64359 - - - - -] DBError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'services.replication_status' in 'field list'") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:31:31.371 7644 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2
    2017-03-06 03:31:13 CRIT    cinder [req-30fb012c-63e6-4612-aa5a-45b53da4ece1 - - - - -] DBError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'services.modified_at' in 'field list'") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:31:13.530 7296 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-
    2017-03-06 03:30:58 CRIT    cinder [req-592f2bd8-f3cf-401d-9fef-c10027032de8 - - - - -] DBError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'services.disabled_reason' in 'field list'") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:30:58.459 6695 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017
    2017-03-06 03:30:39 CRIT    cinder [req-6f2919f0-5bb4-4e80-bcac-2868b1f7a928 - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:30:39.418 6115 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:30:21 CRIT    cinder [req-4573a531-4d9d-4e72-ac57-b06e1d41677e - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:30:21.538 5792 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:30:08 CRIT    cinder [req-b9d8ef0d-5db0-48f0-a50d-2bc7d89a3319 - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:30:08.703 5450 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:29:54 CRIT    cinder [req-6eb92d22-8477-445d-b7a5-1a8c6ff4e78b - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:29:54.084 4837 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:29:35 CRIT    cinder [req-f0be9965-61ec-4346-a1cd-776c6e135e1a - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:29:34.896 4319 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:29:15 CRIT    cinder [req-7666316c-0561-486e-a85d-b24b3da260af - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:29:15.753 3829 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:28:57 CRIT    cinder [req-b698ca43-f1f6-477a-8770-22aac00ecdf5 - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:28:57.706 3107 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:28:38 CRIT    cinder [req-baa64f5a-d01a-4c93-b897-66051a66a077 - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:28:38.164 2663 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:28:21 CRIT    cinder [req-28b9e3b7-7025-4a12-be4f-18eddfc489fd - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:28:21.331 2373 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
    2017-03-06 0
    2017-03-06 03:28:09 CRIT    cinder [req-1a0d12f5-723a-485d-8396-84077b6f80a2 - - - - -] ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'cinder.services' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT services.created_at AS services_created_at, services.updated_at AS services_updated_at, services.deleted_at AS services_deleted_at, services.deleted AS services_deleted, services.id AS services_id, services.host AS services_host, services.`binary` AS services_binary, services.topic AS services_topic, services.report_count AS services_report_count, services.disabled AS services_disabled, services.availability_zone AS services_availability_zone, services.disabled_reason AS services_disabled_reason, services.modified_at AS services_modified_at, services.rpc_current_version AS services_rpc_current_version, services.object_current_version AS services_object_current_version, services.replication_status AS services_replication_status, services.active_backend_id AS services_active_backend_id, services.frozen AS services_frozen \nFROM services \nWHERE services.deleted = false AND services.host = %s AND services.`binary` = %s'] [parameters: ('node-7.domain.tld', 'cinder-scheduler')]
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/bin/cinder-scheduler", line 10, in <module>
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder     sys.exit(main())
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/cmd/scheduler.py", line 54, in main
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder     server = service.Service.create(binary='cinder-scheduler')
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 268, in create
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder     service_name=service_name)
    2017-03-06 03:28:09.430 2141 ERROR cinder   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/service.py", line 139, in __init__
```